# Does the sorted-function behave differently for sets and lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have just attempted to solve the "Climbing the leaderboard" problem on hackerrank.
During my tries I failed many times at the test cases 6-9 with a runtime error.

```
def climbingLeaderboard(ranked, player):
    # Write your code here
    ret = []
    leaderboardSet = set(ranked)
    leaderboard = sorted(leaderboardSet, reverse = True)
    print(leaderboard, player)
    lenght = len(leaderboard)
    for score in player:
        while lenght > 0 and score >= leaderboard[lenght-1]:
            lenght -= 1
        ret.append(lenght+1)

    return ret
```

After changing the leaderboardSet initialisation to

```
leaderboardSet = list(set(ranked))
```

the code worked flawlessly. Since debugging is basically impossible on hackkerrank I am wondering - is there a difference in the sorted function between sets and lists, that would lead to this problem for big sets?

Edit: This is the link to the original problem: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/climbing-the-leaderboard/problem

Comment: Can you add examples for `ranked` and `player` inputs and the resulting expected output?

Comment: What error did you get? `sorted` works with arbitrary iterables to return a sorted `list`.

Comment: @chepner I don't be these contests provide error details - they just report that m of n tests have failed.  They usually use large datasets, so a poor choice of algorithm will trigger a timeout.  Though I don't see how the OP's reported action could improve the runtime.

Comment: @Tzane: https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/29530/input06.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAR6O7GJNX5DNFO3PV&Expires=1649680256&Signature=ogMsW8fi2NgCSGZJbj8FCLSE5tU%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain 
I hope this link works for you. This was one of the tests that failed. More detailed explanation of the task ist here:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/climbing-the-leaderboard/problem

Answer (score 0):

`python` use [Timsort](https://skerritt.blog/timsort/) in its' `sorted` function. It can work blazingly fast if there are already sorted parts of input. `list` imply certain order, whilst `set` imply lack of order. Latter might prevent detect already sorted parts gimmick and thus prevent getting full speed. I run followed tests:

```
import timeit
timeit.timeit(setup='s=list(range(1000))',stmt='sorted(s)')
timeit.timeit(setup='s=set(range(1000))',stmt='sorted(s)')
```

and got following results

```
7.1935602
10.4982897
```